# vue 3 & typescript - Cannot access ComputedRef<> when it is located inside a reactive();

Tags: typescript, reactive-programming, typescript-typings, reactive, vuejs3

```
interface Intf {
    prop: ComputedRef<string>;
}

const obj = {} as Intf;

console.log(obj.prop.value);
```

I have the above code which looks good as what I expected. I can access `obj.prop.value` and no error was thrown from typescript. However, when I put this `ComputedRef<string>` inside another reactive object, I cannot retrieve it back as typescript said the `prop` is in type `string` instead of `ComputedRef<string>`. Let see the following codes:

```
interface Intf {
    prop: ComputedRef<string>;
}

const re = reactive({
    obj: {} as Intf
});

console.log(re.obj.prop.value); // typescript shown error on this line, `re.obj.prop` is with type `string` instead of `ComputedRef<string>`. At the moment, I cannot retrieve `prop.value` by accessing `prop` as well, since prop is a `ComputedRef<string>` and I should get its value by accessing `prop.value`!!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`computed` are refs and as all refs, they are automatically [unwraped](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity-fundamentals.html#access-in-reactive-objects) when used inside object created with `reactive()`

That's the reason why TS tells you `re.obj.prop` is of type string - you don't need to use `.value` to access the value, just use `re.obj.prop`

Comment: let say I have a `reactive({ compute: undefined as ComputedRef<string> | undefined })`. How can I assign a `computed(() => 'value')` in it? I encountered this problem and typescript doesn't allow me to assign the `computed` into `compute` as when the code leaves `reactive` declaration, the `compute` prop is no longer a `ComputedRef<string>`, it becomes a `string` instead!

Comment: well, I see...interesting problem but different from your original question. Maybe you should create new question and somebody will be able to help. I am not..